# Pass a URI as a pgAdmin parameter

Tags: postgresql, linux, pgadmin, heroku

I can connect to Heroku with `psql` passing a URI:

```
$ psql postgres://user:password@ec2-54-243-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d7xkxididkdi
```

I want to do the same with pgAdmin:

```
$ pgadmin3 -qc postgres://user:password@ec2-54-243-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d7xkxididkdi
```

but I get the error message:

```
Unknown token in connection string: <the passed string>
```

Is it possible to pass a URI as parameter to pgAdmin?

Comment: I would have expected a standard libpq connection string to work, [which allows an URI](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-connect.html#AEN41094). But it doesn't seem like that? Nothing definitive in the [online documentation](http://pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/commandline.html) either. If nothing pops up here I suggest you post to the support list: pgadmin-support@postgresql.org. Here's the [list archive](http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgadmin-support/).